# Unable to Access SSL-encrypted MAMP site over LAN using Squid proxy (Non-SSL sites working fine)

Tags: ssl, proxy, unix, https, squid

I've got a development site running on a host machine (mac os x) in MAMP that I want to view on a client machine (and also on mobile devices - all mac os). All are connected to the same LAN (wifi). I have successfully set up a Squid proxy on the host and I can view HTTP hosts on the client in regular browsers. But I am having some real trouble viewing the SSL-encrypted ones. It's important to use SSL in the dev environment because I'm using it on production. I hope someone can help me figure out how to work this! Thanks in advance.

I access the site on the host using `https://www.mydomain.dev:8899`. It works perfectly there in all browsers. The local IPs: host `192.168.0.99`, client `192.168.0.98`.

I set up a little test virtual host in MAMP using the address `http://test.dev:8898`, with no SSL encryption (it just lists a folder). I can access it on the host machine by typing `http://test.dev:8898` into the browser. I created the following `.pac` file and configured the client machine to use it for proxy configuration:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(url, "http://test.dev*")) {
    return "PROXY 192.168.0.99:3128; DIRECT";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

When I started Squid, with the squid config shown below, I could indeed access `http://test.dev:8898` on the client machine in all browsers, just like on the host. Great. Now I set up the following `.pac` file for the dev site:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(url, "https://www.mydomain.dev*")) {
    return "PROXY 192.168.0.99:3128; DIRECT";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

But I was unable to connect to `https://www.mydomain.dev:8899` on the client machine, getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome and 'Unable to Connect' in Firefox (a very quick response in both cases, no noticeable latency).

The `access.log` looks like this for both requests:

```
1486685792.999     58 192.168.0.98 TCP_MISS/200 1258 GET http://test.dev:8898/ - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.0.99 text/html
1486685793.556      1 192.168.0.98 TCP_MISS/404 443 GET http://test.dev:8898/favicon.ico - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.0.99 text/html
1486685797.211      1 192.168.0.98 TCP_DENIED/403 3992 CONNECT www.mydomain.dev:8899 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1486685797.213      0 192.168.0.98 TCP_DENIED/403 3992 CONNECT www.mydomain.dev:8899 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

There's also a weird error in `cache.log` that says:

```
2017/02/09 09:09:42 kid1| WARNING: 'Name-of-host-machine' rDNS test failed: (0) No error.
2017/02/09 09:09:42 kid1| WARNING: Could not determine this machines public hostname. Please configure one or set 'visible_hostname'.
```

Here's the curl output:

```
→ curl -v --proxy 192.168.0.99:3128 https://www.mydomain.dev:8899
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.mydomain.dev:8899/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.0.99...
* Connected to 192.168.0.99 (192.168.0.99) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.mydomain.dev:8899
> CONNECT www.mydomain.dev:8899 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.mydomain.dev:8899
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: squid/3.5.23
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2017 01:54:06 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 3516
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: MISS from localhost
< Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.5.23)
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.99 left intact
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

I tried adding the line `https_port 3130 transparent` under the line `http_port 3128 transparent`, and then used the `.pac` file to redirect to `192.168.0.99:3130`, but that didn't work. The browser just hangs waiting for a connection and eventually says the connection was refused.

Hoping someone will know what these errors mean, and what I'm doing wrong! Thanks so much for your time.

---

Here's my `squid.conf` file:

```
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24 # local subnet

acl SSL_ports port 443 8899
acl Safe_ports port 8899
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 8898  # testdev site
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

http_port 3128 transparent

coredump_dir /usr/local/var/cache/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```